# Where can I operate a PokerBot (and other games) legitimately?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, poker

I'd like to build a PokerBot (and a few other games) for the intellectual challenge. However, I only want to do this in an ethical and legal way.

So, I need a game server where all players and the game operator know that I'm running a pokerbot. Where that's not cheating but the norm. Perhaps even where being a human is against the rules.

(I'd also like to build PlayerBots for other games, not just poker.)

If one doesn't exist already, anyone up for doing a collaborative project to build such an environment?

UPDATE:
I would say that an open API is the ultimate sign of a server open to bots.
No API = Bots not welcome.

Also, I'm happy to play for points rather than real money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [Coding the Wheel](http://www.codingthewheel.com/) series [How I Built a Working Poker Bot](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-poker-bot) to see if he mentions any sites where bots aren't frowned upon, but I'm pretty sure any of the sites that let you play for money will ban you for running a bot.

If you just want to do it for the learning experience or the challenge, try one of the free game sites like [Yahoo! Games](http://games.yahoo.com/all-games) to see if bots are against their terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

[Poker academy](http://www.poker-academy.com/) has a bot API, and they run an online service for bots. It's commercial software though.